# How to get out of php shell command

Tags: php, linux

I use Debian. I wanted check my php version. I typed but by mistake

```
php
```

instead of

```
php - v
```

. And then "php command line" won't take any commands anymore from me. No error no reaction.

I can stop this process using kill command, but I want to know, what is 'php' without option for. And how to stop it, without kill command.

Comment: I didn't see the S on the word shell, and then I stopped reading...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to send EOF (end-of-file) to PHP, which will cause it to exit. Or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to kill it with a SIGINT signal.

**Explanation:** With no command-line arguments PHP is expecting code to be provided on standard input, which is connected to your terminal. This is standard behavior for many UNIX programs, not just PHP. You can type code manually and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> when you're done and PHP will execute the code you typed.

You can see the same behavior with `cat`. If you don't provide a file name `cat` will read from stdin and copy it to stdout. Which means it will echo every line you type until you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to signal EOF.